# Cannot enable all disabled constraints in database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

The end goal here is to get all the constraints in my database turned back on.

Here's some background on what happened. I've a SQL script for a SQL Server database that adds a bunch of records to several tables. I've to disable the foreign key constraints of many tables in the database in order to insert these statements into the tables I want them in. So I used this statement at the beginning of my script to do that.

```
EXEC sp_msforeachtable "ALTER TABLE ? NOCHECK CONSTRAINT all";
```

It disabled all my constraints and all is good. Everything gets put in the tables without errors. Then I use this command to enable all the constraints again.

```
exec sp_msforeachtable @command1="print '?'", 
                       @command2="ALTER TABLE ? WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT all";
```

This is where the error happens. I get this in the console:

> The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK__PW_COLUMN__TABLE__3864608B". The conflict occurred in database "PWTechDocs", table "dbo.PW_TABLES", column 'TABLE_NAME'.

It says the constraint `FK__PW_COLUMN__TABLE__3864608B` is in table `PW_TABLES` so then I run this statement to disable it while I enable all the other constraints.

```
ALTER TABLE PW_TABLES NOCHECK CONSTRAINT FK__PW_COLUMN__TABLE__3B40CD36;
```

Then I get this error when the statement above is run:

> Constraint 'FK__PW_COLUMN__TABLE__3B40CD36' does not belong to table 'PW_TABLES'.

I tried running the same thing in other tables but the constraint is no where to be found. How do I get all the constraints in my database turned on again?

Comment: The constraints are designed to stop inconsistent data from getting into the database.  You disabled the constraints, loaded inconsistent data, and now you want to turn the constraints back on.  It doesn't work like that.  If the data won't go in because the constraints prevent it, you need to fix the data or the load process, not disable the constraints.

Comment: I think the foreign key might belong to the PW_COLUMN_TABLE and is just referencing the PW_TABLES table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find a constraint using this:

```
SELECT  obj.name AS FK_NAME,
    sch.name AS [schema_name],
    tab1.name AS [table],
    col1.name AS [column],
    tab2.name AS [referenced_table],
    col2.name AS [referenced_column]
FROM sys.foreign_key_columns fkc
INNER JOIN sys.objects obj
    ON obj.object_id = fkc.constraint_object_id
INNER JOIN sys.tables tab1
    ON tab1.object_id = fkc.parent_object_id
INNER JOIN sys.schemas sch
    ON tab1.schema_id = sch.schema_id
INNER JOIN sys.columns col1
    ON col1.column_id = parent_column_id AND col1.object_id = tab1.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.tables tab2
    ON tab2.object_id = fkc.referenced_object_id
INNER JOIN sys.columns col2
    ON col2.column_id = referenced_column_id AND col2.object_id = tab2.object_id
```

It will tell you what table it belongs to.

Then you can look at what the constraint is doing... it's likely a missing reference given its a FK violation.

Maybe you have an address table, and you listed a StateID=123 but the State table only has 122 rows.  You have to find the records which have an invalid reference and fix them.

```
SELECT * 
FROM someTable T1 --the table with bad data
LEFT OUTER JOIN someOtherTable T2 ON T1.RefID = T2.ID --the lookup table
WHERE T2.ID IS NULL
```

If any rows come back, check their reference value.  Is it NULL?  Is it 123, but there IS no 123?  You're going to have to find the bad data you added and fix it.

If the constraint is a unique constraint, maybe you put two rows for State 123, you can use this to find duplicates.

```
;WITH DUPES
AS (
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY ID) AS ROWID
FROM myTable
)

SELECT *
-- DELETE
FROM DUPES
WHERE ROWID>1
```

Once you confirm there are dupes, and that you won't be blowing away all your precious data switch the select for a delete...

Once you find the dupes, or fix the invalid pointers, then try to re-enable the constraint... it won't re-enable until you do.

Comment: Thanks for this. One question. How do I find out what the constraint is doing? I'm using SQL Server Management Studio but when I go to the constraints folder in the table there's nothing listed. I do get the constraints back when I run that first query you listed though.

Answer (score 0):

Constraint "FK__PW_COLUMN__TABLE__3864608B" is not in "PW_TABLES" it is referencing "PW_TABLES", to find table associated with "FK__PW_COLUMN__TABLE__3864608B" you need to do the following.

In your SQL Server Management Studio paste your table name in query window (i.e. PW_TABLES)
and **press Alt+F1** you will get complete details for that table.

To see all referencing constraint drag the scroll bar at the bottom. At bottom you will see a column named ***"Table is referenced by foreign keys"*** which will give information about all constraint referencing that table including table name and constraint name.

Find you constraint (i.e. "FK__PW_COLUMN__TABLE__3864608B") and table associated with it and disable it.